# How to call Firefox printpreview via url (not getMostRecentBrowserWindow) using addon SDK

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, gecko

One way I can call printpreview is with getMostRecentBrowserWindow

```
const { getMostRecentBrowserWindow } = require('sdk/window/utils');
var chromewin = getMostRecentBrowserWindow();
chromewin.PrintUtils.printPreview(chromewin.PrintPreviewListener);
```

Now i want to call printpreview with url. Please help me.
Thank you so much.

Comment: It looks like printPreview functions prints the uri of the currently focused document: `this._originalURL = this._sourceBrowser.currentURI.spec;` if you can somehow modify `this._originalURL` you'll get what you want. http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-beta/source/toolkit/components/printing/content/printUtils.js#69