# How to close tab when close printpreview using firefox addon SDK

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

When i was open new tab. I used javascript send message to my addon change  this tab to printpreview mode.

```
setInterval(function(){send_message("print_preview","");},1000);//my command send to addon when domready
$("body").mouseleave(function(e) {                
window.close();                
});
```

When printpreview mode active i can't select printer because source tab was closed. Now i want close tab when i click close printpreview mode (using firefox addon SDK).

Thank you so much

Comment: Could you please be more clear about what you are trying to do?

Comment: Dear Erikvold! I think i need close this question because firefox can't open printpreview if large image load notcomplete . I use setInterval(function(){send_message("print_preview","");},1000); send command every second to callback image load done and use body mouseleave event to trap for close this tab (stop send command). I think this is good solution but  i can't select printer... because source tab was closed. Now i change solution to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22728166/how-to-call-firefox-printpreview-via-url-not-getmostrecentbrowserwindow-using

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23238913/how-to-add-button-in-toolbar-of-print-preview-fire-fox-using-add-sdk/23252892#23252892