# How to add button in toolbar of print preview fire fox using add SDK

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, gecko

How to add button in toolbar of print preview fire fox using add SDK.[image]

thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

```
    function addToolbarButton() {   
        var {Cc, Ci, Cu} = require("chrome");  
    var mediator = Cc['@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1'].getService(Ci.nsIWindowMediator); 
        var document = mediator.getMostRecentWindow("navigator:browser").document; 
        var navBar = document.getElementById("print-preview-toolbar");
        if (!navBar) {
            return;
        }    
        var btn = document.createElement("toolbarbutton");       
        btn.setAttribute('type', 'button');
        btn.setAttribute('class', 'toolbarbutton-1');
        btn.setAttribute('image', data.url('print-on_small.png')); // path is relative to data folder
        btn.setAttribute('orient', 'horizontal');
        btn.setAttribute('label', '  In');
        btn.addEventListener('click', function() {  
            console.log('clicked');
        }, false)
 navBar.appendChild(btn);   
    }
```

[image: done]

Comment: Great of you to share your solution!

Comment: No problem, thank you so much for You and Mr Paa. My project is convert Winform app to web app. I dev this addon to update print mode of browser. It can simulate printing like winform.